# restoreDockWidget not working as expected

Tags: qt

There are some dockwidgets which are created after calling restoreState on main window. Therefore I tried calling restoreDockWidget on that dock windows to restore the state according to previous session but it is not working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just set unique object name for each dock widget:

```
setObjectName("your-dock-N");
```

And you must create all docks before call restoreState() of main window. All docks will be restored.

Comment: But my use case is - there are some docks that are created after calling restoreState() and I want to retain the state of these docks according to last session by calling restoreDockWidget. Also each dock has a unique name. Problem is dock that was visible in last session does not become vsiible in current session by calling restoreDockWidget() (after calling restoreState()).

Comment: @akanshaaggarwal you check returned value of restoreDockWidget()?